# Accessing a struct inside of a private class C++

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am lost in trying to figure out how to access this struct that is inside of the private part of the class. I I would need the code to stay as a struct if that is possible.
Thanks very much for the help.

```
const int MAX_CHAR = 101;
const int NAME_COURSE_WIDTH = 20;
const int DESCRIPTION_WIDTH = 40;
const int DUE_DATE_WIDTH = 20;
const int COURSE_ENTRY_CAPACITY = 100;

class Task
{
private:
    struct CourseEntry
    {
        char course[MAX_CHAR];
        char description[MAX_CHAR];
        char dueDate[MAX_CHAR];
    } course;
public:


    void displayMenu();
    char readInCommand();
    void processCommand(char command, CourseEntry list[], int& listSize);
    void readInEntry(CourseEntry& anEntry);
    void readInCourse(char course[]);

    //database related functions
    void displayAll(const CourseEntry list[], int listsize); 
    void addEntry(const CourseEntry& anEntry, CourseEntry list[], int& listSize);
    bool searchEntry(const char course[], CourseEntry& match, const CourseEntry list[], int listSize);

    void loadCourseEntry(const char fileName[], CourseEntry list[], int& listSize);
    void saveCourseEntry(const char fileName[], const CourseEntry list[], int listSize);

    //standard input tools
    int readInt(const char prompt[]);
    void readString (const char prompt[], char inputStr[], int maxChar);
};
```

Comment: if `CourseEntry` is indeed private then it shouldn't be visible outside of `Task`. It can only be used internally for implementation specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the definition of the struct outside the class, and just keep the variable private:

```
struct CourseEntry
{
    char course[MAX_CHAR];
    char description[MAX_CHAR];
    char dueDate[MAX_CHAR];
}

class Task {
    private:
       CourseEntry course;

    public:

        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better and nicer and will keep encapsulation if you declare your `CourseEntry` structure `public` in the class `Task` and every time you use it just put the class name before like this `Task::CourseEntry`.

So for example a call in `main` will be (C++11 style):

```
 Task myTask;
 //initialize somehow your struct 
 Task::CourseEntry myStruct = {//here you can do it
                              };
 //call readInEntry
 myTask.readInEntry(myStruct);`
```